# Error al llamar a método de una clase, no está definido

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo, jupyter

Me estoy empezando en la programación orientada a objetos en Jupyter notebook y me saltó el siguiente error:

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> NameError  <ipython-input-20-611a8bc01408> in <module>()
>                            Traceback (most recent call last)
> ----> 1 Cuadrante(A)
>
> NameError: name 'Cuadrante' is not defined
> ```

Estoy haciendo un plano cartesiano sin salida gráfica.
Os explico:

- Se crea un punto llamado `A` con las coordenadas 2 y 3.
- Pruebo el método `str` en el punto `A` y funciona.
- Ahora pruebo el método `Cuadrante` y me sale el error.

¿Qué pasa?

Os paso el código:

```
class Punto:
    def __init__(self,x=0,y=0):#----------------Método constructor (Punto)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):#-------------------------Redefiniendo el método str() para devolver posición
        return("{}, {}".format(self.x, self.y))

    def Cuadrante(self):#-----------------------Devuelve el Nº de cuadrante

        if self.x > 0 and self.y > 0:#----------Cuadrante 1
            print("el punto {} ({},{}) se encuentra en el 1er cuadrante".format(self, self.x, self.y))

        if self.x < 0 and self.y > 0:#----------Cuadrante 2
            print("el punto {} ({},{}) se encuentra en el 2º cuadrante".format(self, self.x, self.y))

        if self.x < 0 and self.y < 0:#----------Cuadrante 3
            print("el punto {} ({},{}) se encuentra en el 3er cuadrante".format(self, self.x, self.y))

        if self.x > 0 and self.y < 0:#----------Cuadrante 4
            print("el punto {} ({},{}) se encuentra en el 4º cuadrante".format(self, self.x, self.y))

        else:#----------------------------------Punto de orígen
            print("El punto {} ({},{}) se encuentra en el pº de orígen".format(self, self.x, self.y))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás llamando mal al método, no se llama a un método de instancia  con `Cuadrado(A)`, sino `A.Cuadrado()`, siendo `A` un objeto de la clase `Punto`. Es decir la sintaxis es:

```
instancia.método_de_instancia(arg1, arg2, ....)
```

Posiblemente la confusión viene de `str(A)`, pero en este caso **estás llamado al built-in [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) no al método `__str__`** de forma directa. `str` trata de retornar la representación en forma de cadena del objeto, simplificando, internamente primero llamar al método `__str__` del objeto `(objeto.__str__()`), si esto falla porque el método no esté definido usa la salida del método  `__repr__` que toda clase tiene. Esta operación también se produce de forma implícita cuando imprimimos el objeto.

Por lo tanto, no es cierto que con `def __str__(self)` sobrescribes `str`, sobrescribes el método `__str__` si la clase hereda de otra que lo implementa, en caso contrario simplemente defines el método `__str__` en tu clase, que luego eventualmente puede usar la función `str`, pero son cosas distintas.

Teniendo entonces tu clase:

```
class Punto:
     def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):  #----------------Método constructor (Punto)
         self.x = x
         self.y = y

     def __str__(self):  #-------------------------Redefiniendo el método str() para devolver posición
         return("{}, {}".format(self.x, self.y))

     def cuadrante(self):  #-----------------------Devuelve el Nº de cuadrante

         if self.x > 0 and self.y > 0:  #----------Cuadrante 1
             print("El punto {} ({},{}) se encuentra en el 1er cuadrante".format(self, self.x, self.y))

         elif self.x < 0 and self.y > 0:  #----------Cuadrante 2
             print("El punto {} ({},{}) se encuentra en el 2º cuadrante".format(self, self.x, self.y))

         elif self.x < 0 and self.y < 0:  #----------Cuadrante 3
             print("El punto {} ({},{}) se encuentra en el 3er cuadrante".format(self, self.x, self.y))

         elif self.x > 0 and self.y < 0:  #----------Cuadrante 4
             print("El punto {} ({},{}) se encuentra en el 4º cuadrante".format(self, self.x, self.y))

         else:  #----------------------------------Punto de orígen
             print("El punto {} ({},{}) se encuentra en el pº de orígen".format(self, self.x, self.y))
```

Veamos un ejemplo:

> ```
> >>> p = Punto(7, -13)    # Instanciación del objeto
>
> >>> str(p)               # Llamada al built-in str
> '7, -13'
>
> >>> p.__str__()          # Llamada explícita a __str__
> '7, -13'
>
> >>> print(p)             # Imprimimos el objeto
> 7, -13
>
> >>> p.cuadrante()        # Llamada al método cuadrado
> El punto 7, -13 (7,-13) se encuentra en el 4º cuadrante
> ```

Observa que el parámetro `self` (en realidad este nombre es una convención) que no es más que una referencia al objeto en si mismo y que todo método de instancia ha de recibir como primer parámetro, es pasado de forma automática al método. En realidad lo anterior "equivale" a:

```
>>> Punto.cuadrante(p)
El punto 7, -13 (7,-13) se encuentra en el 4º cuadrante
```

> **Nota:** observa que he cambiado los `if` encadenados por `elif`, Si usas `if` encadenados todas las condiciones son evaluadas siempre, lo cual es ineficiente y no tiene sentido, ya que si el punto está en un cuadrante no va a estar en otro. Con una construcción `if-elif-else` en el momento que una condición se cumple el resto ni se evalúan.

Lo métodos con doble subrayado al principio y al final son [métodos especiales](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names), muchos de ellos tiene una función preconstruida u operador que los usa y no deben por norma general ser usados directamente, por ejemplo `__add__` usado por el operador `+`, `__eq__` por `==`, `__float__` por `float()`, `__abs__` por `abs()`, `__iadd__` por `+=` y un largo etcétera. Su definición o sobrescritura nos permite por ejemplo sobrecargar operadores. Por ejemplo, ahora no puedes saber si dos puntos son iguales (mismo valor para `x` e `y`):

```
>>> p1 = Punto(3, 13)
>>> p2 = Punto(3, 13)
>>> p1 == p2
False
```

Pero si quieres implementar esto basta con sobrescribir el método 
`__eq__`:

```
 def __eq__(self, other):
     if isinstance(other, Punto):
          if self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y: 
               return True
     return False
```

Con lo que ahora si comparamos dos instancias de Punto:

> ```
> >>> p1 = Punto(3, 13)
> >>> p2 = Punto(3, 13)
> >>> p1 == p2
> True
> >>> p3 = Punto(3, 17)
> >>> p1 == p3
> False
> ```

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias pero lo del if fué a la hora de copiar el código ya que en el código original lo tengo con elif. ¡Gracias por todo!